# Date and Time comparison in Java

Tags: java, android

I am comparing two date and time but it is not working as expected. Please help me.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Date date1=convertStringToDate("2015-05-03T17:11:00Z");
        Date date2=convertStringToDate("2015-05-08T22:02:20Z");
        System.out.println("Date2:"+date1.compareTo(date2));//output 1

        Date date3=convertStringToDate("2015-05-08T21:15:29Z");
        System.out.println("Date3:"+date1.compareTo(date3));//output -1

        Date date4=convertStringToDate("2015-05-08T19:22:25Z");
        System.out.println("Date4:"+date1.compareTo(date4));//output -1

        Date date5=convertStringToDate("2015-05-08T16:46:31Z");
        System.out.println("Date5:"+date1.compareTo(date5));//output 1

        Date date6=convertStringToDate("2015-05-08T15:48:02Z");
        System.out.println("Date6:"+date1.compareTo(date6));//output 1


    }

     static  Date convertStringToDate(String input){

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:SS'Z'");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(input);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return  date;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got your `m`'s and `M`'s backwards in the format you're instantiating the `SimpleDateFormat` with. Also, you probably want lowercase `s`'s for the seconds.

Comment: i did not understand it. Please type in the proper format if possible

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`. See [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: It seems to be working fine buddy. Thanks a lot. You can post your comment as answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your test dates, the format `String` you're passing to the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor appears to have the lowercase and uppercase `m`'s mixed up. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), uppercase `M` indicates a *month in year* character, while a lowercase `m` indicates *minute in hour*. Also, you probably want lowercase `s`'s for *seconds*, instead of uppercase `S`'s, which indicate *fractional seconds* characters.

It would seem that the format you want is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`.

Answer (score 0):

## Swap `m` letters

The comment is correct, you need to fix your format pattern by swapping the uppercase and lowercase `m` letters.

Better yet, save yourself much pain by avoiding the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes altogether.

## ISO 8601

Your input strings are in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Both Joda-Time and java.time use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing and generating textual representations of date-time values. So no need to even define a parsing pattern. Simply feed those strings to the constructor of a `DateTime` in Joda-Time, or equivalent in java.time.

## Avoid old date-time classes

You are using old date-time classes that have proven to be poorly designed and troublesome. Avoid them.

Instead use java.time, or its outmoded predecessor [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

### java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

#### Parse as `Instant`

[Parse directly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) into [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) objects. An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant a = Instant.parse( "2015-05-03T17:11:00Z" );
Instant b = Instant.parse( "2015-05-08T22:02:20Z" );
```

Compare with the usual `compareTo` method.

```
int comparison = a.compareTo( b );
```

You can also compare with [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#isBefore-java.time.Instant-), and [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#isAfter-java.time.Instant-) methods.

Tip: ISO 8601 strings may have a fractional second with either a dot (period) or a comma as the decimal mark. The java.time classes support the dot by default, so you may want to replace any comma with a dot.

```
Instant a = Instant.parse( "2015-05-03T17:11:00,123456789Z".replace( "," , "." ) );
```

### Joda-Time

```
DateTime dateTime_1 = new DateTime( "2015-05-03T17:11:00Z" , DateTimeZone.UTC ) ;
…
Boolean isEarlier = dateTime_.isBefore( dateTime_2 ) ;
```